# ::before wrapper element blocks input

Tags: html, css

::before element of style .betInfo_rou blocks input area. I don't have access to the input because ::before over everything. When I delete it, it works. How can I fix this? Before displays background for the whole wrap.

```
.betInfo_rou{
  grid-area: 2/1/3/2;
  position: relative;
  &::before{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 71.71%
      );
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: -68 * $vert-1;
  }
 }
<div class="betInfo_rou">
      <div class="betValue_rou">
        <P>Bet</P>
        <div class="inputBox_bs1">
          <label class="input-sizer1">
            <input
              type="text"
            />
            <img src="../../Assets/SvgIcons/blackChip.svg" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: switch it to `::after`

Comment: @DevMan i tried, nothing changed

Comment: added to ::before `transform: translateY(-20px)`. this is move `::before` to up on 20px.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov I need to keep background position. I can move it without transform. I guess need to move background back or any property for ignore , but idk how

Comment: @fetixzz then I don't understand what is the problem. if your ::before closes the input field, then it needs to be removed or moved. or adjust the size of the input field so that it does not close. But that piece of code that you provided is not visible.

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet which shows the problem. What for example is $vert-1 and have you considered z-index? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth it's what i needed, thank you. I completely forgot about z-index

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointer-events: none` to make browsers ignore mouse and touch interactions on the pseudoelement and pass them to other elements.

```css
.betInfo_rou {
  grid-area: 2/1/3/2;
  position: relative;
}

.betInfo_rou::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 71.71%
  );
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -68 * $vert-1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="betInfo_rou">
  <div class="betValue_rou">
    <P>Bet</P>
    <div class="inputBox_bs1">
      <label class="input-sizer1">
        <input type="text" />
        <img src="../../Assets/SvgIcons/blackChip.svg" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```